# How to copy mutiple sheets from one workbook to another; without copying VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy all sheets (7 sheets) from workbook1(wb1) to wb2. wb1 contains command buttons but I don't want them in my new workbook. I am using loop to copy individual sheets from one workbook to another. but error comes while copying to 2nd sheet. I am using the code as below :-

```
 Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add
    With wb2
    .Title = "My Sales"
    .Subject = "Sales"
    .SaveAs Filename:="mysales.xls"
    End With
    For i = 1 To 7
    Dim row As Long
    Dim column As Long
    wb1.Activate
    wb1.Sheets(i).Activate
      column = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
      row = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(row, column)).Select
     Selection.Copy
      wb2.Sheets(i).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
    next i
End Sub
```

Loop is running succesfully for the first time but for i=2, code gives error

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub M_snb()
  thisworkbook.sheets(array("one","two","three","four","five","six","seven")).copy

  do until activeworkbook.sheets("one").oleobjects.count=0
   activeworkbook.sheets("one").oleobjects(1).delete
  loop
  activeworkbook.saveas "G:\OF\new.xlsx",51
End Sub
```